# Updating Python dictionaries contents dynamically

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been experimenting with python and more specifically dictionaries.

I'm currently trying to add content created dynamically to a dictionary.

I started by initializing the dictionary without any content:

```py
jsonCommentOutput = {}
```

I've already tried some approaches but so far I haven't managed to reach the output I'm looking for.

Like this:

```py
jsonCommentOutput["comments"][i] = ([{"comment": dynamic_content}])
i+=1
```

Or like this:

```py
jsonCommentOutput["comments"] = ([{"comment": dynamic_content}])
```

By the end I want to have something similar to the following:

```py
"comments": [
        {
          "comment": "bla."
        },
        {
          "comment": "bla bla."
        },
        {
          "comment": "bla bla bla."
        }
      ]
```

But so far I'm just getting something like, where the only element shown is the last content generated:

```py
"comments": [
        {
          "comment": "bla bla bla."
        }
      ]
```

Comment: a list of comments is not a dict of comments.  It looks like you need a list here to iterate across each comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing dictionaries with lists. Try something like:

```
data = {"comments": []}
data["comments"].append({"comment": "foo"})
data["comments"].append({"comment": "bar"})
```

the value of `data` would then be:

```
{'comments': [{'comment': 'foo'}, {'comment': 'bar'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was indeed mixing the concepts of dictionaries and lists!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the expected output of a list of dicts, you should append dicts to a list instead.

Initialize the list with:

```
jsonCommentOutput["comments"] = []
```

and then after the code where a new value of `dynamic_content` is obtained:

```
jsonCommentOutput["comments"].append({"comment": dynamic_content})
```